# Unresolved Inclusion Inside <xc.h> Header File

Tags: include, pic

After inspecting what was wrong with the generic inclusion file `<xc.h>`, I've found that the `#include <p24EP32MC202.h>` (The PIC Microcontroller I'm using) file has an error, which is described by the IDE as an "Unresolved directive". Beneath it, this text follows:

> *Analyzed user include paths and include headers:*
> *C:\MTT\TLS0101\R1-01.X\C_INCLUDE_PATH*
> *Analyzed system include paths:*
> *C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc16\v1.50\include\lega-c*
> *C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc16\v1.50\support\generic\h*
> *Include path trail to current file:*
> *C:\MTT\TLS0101\R1-01.X\Source.c: (Line 1)*

If anyone could translate what it's asking me to change, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check your include path on project properties. I guess there is no error in the controller header file.

Comment: As it turns out, this was exactly the issue. Thanks.